# How do you make a single falling edge pulse when a falling edge is detected?

Tags: power-electronics, components, component-selection

[image: Circut diagram of circuit im designing]

im designing a circuit where when the switch is open, the 555 timer ic's output goes high but in real life, for the 555 timer to go back to a LOW state, the trigger pin needs to be higher than 1/3 Vcc so im looking for a component or a solution that allows a single pulse which is always HIGH but goes low when detecting a falling edge and immediately or after a sec or 2 goes back to HIGH.
What I want the input waveform to look like into 555 timer

[image]

Comment: why use a 555 here? (in other words, is there a timing aspect that you did not specify in your question? It is fairly unclear what you want your circuit to do, actually, and what your actual input signal looks like.)

Comment: and by the way, LED without series resistor: bad idea!

Comment: The circuit requires you to have a timer that waits before turning on the LED so the 555 timer is there and I will also put a resistor there as per your suggestion. As for the input signal into the 555 timer IC, i want it to be a waveform that is always high but goes low when the switch is open but goes back high immediately after or a second after. I'm not sure if that is possible

Comment: I still dont understand, draw a waveform of expected output for a given input to make it clearer. Anyway, the search term you're probably looking for is "monostable 555 circuit". Go to http://www.falstad.com/circuit/ and click "Circuits -> 555 timer chip -> monostable multivibrator", then click and hold the "H" symbol in the schematic to send your input signal

Comment: @Miron Well, a monostable can be built with a 555, but given there's already a logic level device in there, a simple capacitor charged or discharged through a switch would do – no need for a 555, honestly...

Comment: i need it because i need to set a specific timing to 10s and I have been taught how to use a 555 timer but not a capacitor to time

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/ybrvu9rf
here is a basic monostable that's how i want it to work. with an input that goes HIGH always and when I push the switch it goes low than when I release the switch goes back to high and the output just a timing period of my choice